# Android Studio add current project to a git repository

Tags: git, android-studio, repository, azure-devops

I currently have a android project and I want to add it to my Visual Studio Online repository.
How can I do that?

If I enable version control integration and choose git I will have a local git repository..I want to set somewhere the URL of my repository such as

```
https://myusername.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/ProjectName
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This Git command will add a reference to your *remote* repository with the name "origin" to your *local* repository.

```
git remote add origin https://myusername.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/ProjectName
```

More info : https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

Comment: I did this, opened cmd from the .git folder in the project and wrote that you told me (with the url of the repository) I did commit and push and got 148 files committed: initial
8:41:49 PM Push rejected: master: rejected ...I was never asked for a password and username for the repository.. And now my .git folder dissapeared

Comment: this is probably another problem actually. like server configuration or something ;)